# Проблемы с сохранением в ексель,капризная либа EPPlus

Tags: c#

использую код для сохранения

```cs
var excel = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();

var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet-name");
// you can also use LoadFromCollection with an `IEnumerable<SomeType>`
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light1);
ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address.ToString()].AutoFitColumns(5,15);
                    
using (var file = File.Create(dia.FileName))
    excel.SaveAs(file);
```

Все отлично работает и сохраняет НО!

1. Если лист назван несколькими словами через пробелы EPPlus ругается
2. Если в 1-й строке (которая заголовки) есть дубли EPPlus опять ругается

Мож кто работает с либой плотно и вкурсе как обойти ее капризы?
Подсобите светлой мыслью буду премного благодарен за дельные советы!

Ругается на пробел так

```
System.ArgumentException: Tablename has spaces
```

Ругается на одинаковые заголовки так

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Table ExportProductsSheet Column Характеристика does not have a unique name.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не описывайте проблему словами "ругается". Вместо этого старайтесь добавлять как можно больше информации об ошибке, которую выводит программа или компилятор.

Comment: Попробуйте другие библиотеки для работы с экселем, их несколько было для C#, с разным набором возможностей. Сейчас я уже не помню названий, давно было.

Comment: https://github.com/AntonNikolaevmyname/AutoSertificate-.NET попробуй с этой прогой решить свою проблему, может поможет. там либа microsoft.interop.excel

Comment: Используйте [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia)

Comment: Interop.Excel  пробывал у нее свои проблемы она слишком тормозная, поиграть можно если у тебя десяток строк но если 10к выгрузку слишком долго ждать

Comment: Если не ленивый, пробуй вот это https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/